# Change overall tintColor and font-size of UITableViewCellStyleValue2 textLabel in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, tintcolor

I have a `Skinning` module where I define my app wide `tintColor` for general use in the app:

```
+ (UIColor*)tintColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.26f green:0.41f blue:1.00f alpha:1.00f];
}
```

and I use this to set the app's overall tint color:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.tintColor = [Skinning tintColor];
```

But `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`'s `textLabel color remained the same.  So I have to do:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [Skinning tintColor];
```

for each and every cell.

I suppose there's no overall way to set this once, or is there?

I have the same issue for the font-size.  By default it's 15 points, but in iOS Setting etc. they used the 18 points system-font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem before, and I think the best solution is to write a custom subclass of UITableViewCell and set up the various textLabels color in an overridden cell constructor (e.g. `– initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`).
In the same spot you can also set the font sizes.

Another approach (which doesn't seem to fit well in your case) would be to use the `UIAppearance` proxy for labels contained in table view cells, but then the appearance  would be set for every cell class, every label (main and detail), every style:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setTextColor:[Skinning tintColor]];
```

There seems to be no way for doing it only for certain table view cell styles.